# Fortran dependency management and dynamic config-/documentfile merges using "maven equivalent"

Tags: maven, fortran, dependency-management

I have a large project written mostly in FORTRAN90 consisiting of a core and numerous add-on modules also written in FORTRAN90. At any given time I'd like to be able to:

- package the core module together with any number of the modules
- create a new config-file merging the core-config and module-configs
- merge the various latex-files from the core and modules

The code+configs+documentation lives in SVN...

Can/shall MAVEN be used for this use-case?

******* UPDATE *******
@haraldkl:
Ok, I'll try to elaborate as it definitely is in my interest to gather as much info as possible on this - I really appreciate the comments I get!

My project contains a core module which is mandatory. In order to add additional functionality you may select an arbitrary number of add-on modules. The core and each module resides in their own directory and is under SVN-control. For a given delivery I would like to be able to select the "core" and an arbitrary number of modules and calculate the dependency chain in order to build the modules in the correct order as they sometimes, unfortunately, might have cross-dependencies. When the build order has been set I need to be able to merge property-files from the selected modules with the property-file for the "core" so I end-up with an assembled/aggregated property-file with the aggregated properties from the "core" and all the selected modules. The same goes for the latex-files: I'd like to get an assembled document based on the "core" + the selected modules latex-files, thus ending up with one latex-file.

So, the bottom line: a solution something like:

1. tick selected modules to go with the delivery (core is mandatory so no need to tick)
2. click "Assemble" (code is gathered from SVN)
3. The solution calculates correct build order
4. The solution merges property-files -> "package.property"
5. The solution merges latex-files -> "document.latex"

Currently we use make under UNIX but I'm a little uncertain as to what extent make is able to handle 4 and 5 above.

DONE!

Comment: It's a little unclear to me what your config file refers to, would that be a automake configure file? We are using waf (https://waf.io) to configure and build Fortran, works quite nice and offers a great deal of flexibility. Not sure wether that would suite you here. Maybe you could provide a little more information on what exactly you want to achieve. Putting sources together, and accompany them with an automatically generated build infrastructure?

Comment: Hmmmm, I'll try to explain :) The config-files are module-specific which means that the core-module and the optional modules have one config-file each. What I would like to accomplish is to have a tool which makes it possible to establish the dependency tree in such a way that when I decide to, say, build a specific setup consisting of, say, core+moduleA+moduleE+moduleL would result in a config-file built up using the config-fragments from core+A+E+L. The same process would be used for the latex files.

Comment: There are several tools to build Fortran dependencies for a given set of files, waf does this internally, but you would need to modify it to write it out for you. One option might for example be http://lagrange.mechse.illinois.edu/f90_mod_deps/, also have a look at http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Build+tools I don't know about Maven. The problem is, that this probably also depends on what you want to with it, and it still is not quite clear what config in your context refers to.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't name them config-files as it might be confusing, maybe property-file would be a better word to explain the purpose of the files. In the example I gave with the 'core+A+E+L' above I was referring to the fact that the result of the build of those modules would result in a merged property-file consisting of sections related to each individual module. The same goes for the latex-files...

Comment: I'll just observe that I think Maven is relatively uncommon in the Fortran world.  make and CMake are much more commonly encountered.  I'm not sure what Maven does that CMake doesn't, but that's a matter of personal ignorance.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but as of now it is a little bit unclear, at least to me, what the specific requirements are, could you please try to elaborate a little in your question?

Comment: CMake does what it sounds like you want.

Comment: @haraldkl: Ok, I'll try to elaborate as it definitely is in my interest to gather as much info as possible on this:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on it:

I believe steps 1 to 3 are completely achievable with commonly used configuration tools. Also steps 4 and 5 present, as far as I can see, just another build task, there is no reason why Make should not be able to do that. I regularly generate files for LaTeX processing via Make and then assemble them with latexmk mostly. The main point is how to select what to merge and how it has to be merged, you are a little bit unclear on the how, the what should be handled by the configuring system. Your choice probably also depends on what should be done at the end of step 3. Should the code actually be compiled, or do you need to have some written out version of the dependencies?

Traditional configure system on Unix is the [autotools suite](http://www.sourceware.org/autobook/). However, as far as I know, it does not support the identification of Fortran dependencies out of the box, and you would need to enhance it in that direction.

A popular replacement for the autotools is [CMake](http://www.cmake.org), which [does include](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMakeForFortranExample) Fortran dependency resolution. It might best suite your needs as pointed out by casey, as it allows you to create [various generators](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-generators.7.html), so for example you could have it generating an appropriate Makefile for your selection of files.

[Waf](https://waf.io) gives you great deal of flexibility to handle steps 4 and 5 in your list, it is also capable to identify Fortran dependencies, but I think, it is not as straight forward to generate for example Makefiles out of it as in CMake. The flexibility here is due to the fact, that your waf scripts are just ordinary Python scripts, so you could easily utilize any Python tools in your workflow and describe steps 4 and 5 in any complicated manner you desire.

[Maven](https://maven.apache.org) can [compile Fortran](http://mark.donszelmann.org/maven-nar-plugin/) code, though I do not have any experience with it, I would doubt that it also gives you automatic Fortran dependency resolution. In my understanding, it is not quite as well fit for your setup as the other tools.

The [Fortranwiki](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Build+tools) has some more tools, for example you could come up with your own environment building Makefiles and use [makedepf90](http://personal.inet.fi/private/erikedelmann/makedepf90/) to generate the dependencies.